# How to get rows from DB by many id-s

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an array of ids of bids from one table,  and I have to get bids from `bids` table by these ids. Is it possible to get them with one query  without making many many queries to DB or making super long query with

```
WHERE ... 
  AND ... 
  AND ...
   -- etc
```

with PDO ??? and "views in DB" are also not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need something like:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM bids b
WHERE id IN (SELECT bid_id FROM table1);
```

Or maybe:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM bids b
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.bid_id = b.id);
```

That is, you should ideally handle this within MySQL, if you can.  Once you bring your array of bid IDs out of the database and into PHP, you will have to do more work to find the matches.

Answer (score 1):

You make a join on the two tables (your first table, that I called `first_table` since you didn't specify what it was called) on their common IDs, that will fetch all the results where the ID exists in both tables.

Adjust column-names and table-names accordingly.

```
SELECT b.*
FROM first_table a
JOIN bids b
  ON b.id = a.id
```